# # in XML namespace seems to be causing exceptions in java API--why?

Tags: java, xml, api

In using Python 3.7 and the Requests library to submit a string of XML to an API for a product, I was receiving the following exception back:

```
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.]
```

Search results here and elsewhere largely dealt with the Unicode BOM issues possible when reading a file in, but I finally realized that the issue seems to be the namespace:

```
<feed version="0.3" xmlns="http://some.uri/here/now#">
```

If i remove the #, so the xmlns value reads

```
xmlns="http://some.uri/here/now"
```

or if I add a space between the # and the ", so the whole tag reads:

```
<feed version="0.3" xmlns="http://some.uri/here/now# ">
```

Then the API consumes my request and gives a real response back. I'm confused though--I'm familiar with escaping < > & and so on, but what's going on here?

The response from the API in all cases contains the feed tag as I've given it originally, which is extra confusing as I wouldn't think it would turn right around and generate the invalid XML it was just complaining about.

Edit: as requested the full response from the API is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><feed version="0.3" xmlns="http://purl.org/atom/ns#"><title>Exception processing request.</title><generator uri="http://www.tidalsoftware.com">TES</generator><modified>2019-02-22T16:00:05.012-05:00</modified><entry><id>1</id><title/><content>javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.]
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown Source)
    at com.tidalsoft.framework.xml.XmlSerializer.deserialize(XmlSerializer.java:285)
    at com.tidalsoft.framework.atom.AtomSerializer.deserialize(AtomSerializer.java:120)
    at com.tidalsoft.webclient.tes.dsp.DataSourceProviderImpl$ProcessRequest.initialize(DataSourceProviderImpl.java:3200)
    at com.tidalsoft.framework.execute.Execution.execute(Execution.java:25)
    at com.tidalsoft.framework.execute.Execution.execute(Execution.java:17)
    at com.tidalsoft.webclient.tes.dsp.DataSourceProviderImpl.processRequest(DataSourceProviderImpl.java:950)
    at com.tidalsoft.webclient.tes.dsp.DataSourceProviderImpl.processRequest(DataSourceProviderImpl.java:847)
    at com.tidalsoft.clientmgr.logic.DataSourceManager$DataSourceWrapper$MessageListener.onMessage(DataSourceManager.java:282)
    at com.tidalsoft.framework.jms.MessageSink.fireMessage(MessageSink.java:210)
    at com.tidalsoft.framework.jms.MessageSink.access$000(MessageSink.java:16)
    at com.tidalsoft.framework.jms.MessageSink$1.onMessage(MessageSink.java:84)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession.run(ActiveMQSession.java:833)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQQueueSession.run(ActiveMQQueueSession.java:355)
    at com.tidalsoft.framework.jms.ServerSessionPool$ServerSession.run(ServerSessionPool.java:240)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    ... 21 more
</content><source>ERROR</source></entry></feed>
```

Comment: Have you tried `%23`.

Comment: `#` is a special character in a URL (fragment separator), so it must be escaped.

Comment: *"I'm familiar with escaping `<` `>` `&` and so on"* Those are special characters in XML (and HTML). That has nothing to do with URL, which has its own set of special characters.

Comment: @Andreas, so being that it's a fragment separator, that implies that the parser is trying to interpret the URI as http://some.uri/here/now#">  ?

Comment: Is the XML parsing error because the request you're sending is malformed or because the response you get back from the API is malformed?  Perhaps there's a bug in the API which is triggered when the namespace URI ends with a `#` and you get back an error page instead of some XML?  Please edit your question to include the full traceback and the code you are using to call the API.

Comment: The fragment identifier (value after `#`) is a reference to some location *inside* the resource referenced by the URL. As a namespace, it makes no sense to have a fragment identifier, so either stop using `#`, or escape it so it's not a fragment separator.

Comment: I don't know the answer to the question, but I find all the above explanations unconvincing. Namespace URIs are generally transparent strings. A few products (e.g. XOM) complain if the namespace name isn't a valid absolute URI, but that would surely result in a more specific message. I wonder if the clue lies in the fact that the request originated from Python?

Comment: @LukeWoodward I've edited in the full API response--this represent a good response containing an exception from the API, no?

This exception seems to normally pertain to Unicode BOM issues so perhaps you're right that it's a bug.

Comment: @Andreas with the info I have, definitely agree that the # isn't meaningful

Comment: @MichaelKay You'd think--but I've seen a number of comments researching this to the effect of this SaxParseException being very nondescriptive.

Comment: @Azide I would agree with Michael. You probably should dump your HTTP call (down at the TCP level or equivalent) to actually check what the content is. I have seen no occurence of this error that was not linked to a bad prolog (e.g. a BOM indeed, someone uploading multipart/form content when the API expected application/octet-stream or XML, and the like).

Comment: Thanks for editing in the stacktrace, that contains a lot of further details.  That stacktrace shows that there's a lot more moving parts than I had first imagined: it's not just that you've sent malformed XML to the API which the API immediately rejected.  The exception is thrown deep in some processing of the message by what appears to be TidalSoft Enterprise Scheduler: it's possible that there's a bug in that, or in ActiveMQ or JAXB, which also appear.  I doubt that there's a problem with your Python code.

Comment: You could also try sending a string of intentionally-malformed XML to the API to see what error comes back.  I would guess you would get a different error.

Comment: @LukeWoodward it turns out that this API is expecting application/x-www-form-urlencoded data (so, faking a form submission I guess?) rather than a straight XML payload---but even still, what a peculiar error, and after the things we've looked at in this thread it makes me think something's up with the parsing.